how can i get session inside getServerSideProps function and inside api routes in next js
import UserProfile from '../components/profile/user-profile';
// import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from './api/auth/[...nextauth]';
function ProfilePage() {
  return <UserProfile />;
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
  const session= await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)
  console.log('here')
  console.log(session)
  if(!session){
    return{
      redirect:{
        destination:'/auth',
        permanent : false
      }
    }
  }
  return{
    props:{session}
  }
}
export default ProfilePage;

//Auth options
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"; // Update import for credentials provider
import connectToDatabase from "../../../ib/db";
import { verifyPassword } from "../../../ib/auth";

export const authOptions ={
    session: {
        jwt: true, 
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const client = await connectToDatabase(); 
                const userCollection = client.db().collection('users');
                
                const user = await userCollection.findOne({ email: credentials.email });
                if (!user) {
                    client.close();
                    throw new Error('No User Found!');
                }

                const isValid = await verifyPassword(credentials.password, user.password);
                if (!isValid) {
                    client.close();
                    throw new Error('Invalid password');
                }

                client.close();
                return { email: user.email }; 
            },
        }),
    ],
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions); 

//api route
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import connectToDatabase from "../../../ib/db";
import { hashPassword, verifyPassword } from "../../../ib/auth";
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "PATCH") {
    return res.status(405).json({ message: "Method not allowed" });
  }
  const session = await getServerSession(req,res,authOptions);
  if (!session) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "unAuthorized Request" });
  }
  const userEmail = session.user.email;
  const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;

  const client = await connectToDatabase();
  const usersCollection = client.db().collection('users');

  const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ email: userEmail });
  if (!user) {
    client.close();
    return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User Not Found' });
  }

  const currentPassword = user.password;
  const passwordsAreEqual = await verifyPassword(oldPassword, currentPassword); // Added `await`
  if (!passwordsAreEqual) {
    client.close();
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "You are authenticated but not authorized" });
  }

  const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(newPassword); 
  const result = await usersCollection.updateOne(
    { email: userEmail },
    { $set: { password: hashedPassword } }
  ); 

  client.close();
  return res.status(200).json({ message: "Password updated" });
}

export default handler;

in the above code i  need to get the current session of user inside server side rendering for client side the getSeesion() funcion works fine but inside api routes and getServerProps the getSession() function didnt work and now i am trying to use the getServerSession() which is clearing all the cookies and i am getting null session how can i fix this issue
Also i am getting this error message
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n' +
    '    at gcmDecrypt (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\jose\\dist\\node\\cjs\\runtime\\decrypt.js:67:15)\n' +  
    '    at decrypt (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\jose\\dist\\node\\cjs\\runtime\\decrypt.js:92:20)\n' +     
    '    at flattenedDecrypt (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\jose\\dist\\node\\cjs\\jwe\\flattened\\decrypt.js:143:52)\n' +
    '    at async compactDecrypt (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\jose\\dist\\node\\cjs\\jwe\\compact\\decrypt.js:18:23)\n' +
    '    at async jwtDecrypt (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\jose\\dist\\node\\cjs\\jwt\\decrypt.js:8:23)\n' + 
    '    at async Object.decode (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\next-auth\\jwt\\index.js:66:7)\n' +
    '    at async Object.session (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\routes\\session.js:43:28)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\index.js:165:27)\n' +
    '    at async getServerSession (D:\\personal\\authentication\\node_modules\\next-auth\\next\\index.js:159:19)\n' +      
    '    at async getServerSideProps (webpack-internal:///./pages/profile.js:25:21)',
  name: 'JWEDecryptionFailed'
}

